# Flyer footnote about patent & trade mark?

Tags: expressions, droit-et-justice

I am translating a French product flyer. At the bottom, they write:

> brevets, marque et modèles déposés

I guess this means something like patent pending, or trade mark reserved... but I feel quite uncomfortable with this guess. Is it some standard phrase, with a standard translation?

Comment: This french sentence is one of several forms to explain there are copyrights related to the elements presented in the flyer. For the translation in english, I suggest you this community : http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @cl-r I'm asking for the "meaning" of this phrase. So it's about understanding French, and I thought this site covers this. By the way, I used linguee but the translations are kinda inconsistent. Just wanted to ask here because some French native speaker might explain it so I understand it better.

Comment: @leemes -- C'est votre point de vue, vous noterez cependant que la réponse que vous avez reçue donne les termes en anglais, termes qu'un francophone (qui ne connaît que *l'anglais d'aéroport*) ne maîtrise pas de manière certaine. Le commentaire d'*Eria* vous invite aussi à reconsidérer l'emplacement de vos questions selon la langue dans laquelle le cœur des réponses (qui peuvent être présentées en anglais sur FL-SE) doit être exprimé -- Linguee est loin d'être parfait, mais les exemples sont des traductions effectives qui donnent le contexte des mots affiché dans le dictionnaire d'en-tête.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means there are copyrights on the brand and on the product the flyer shows.

Comment: Thank you! But it says nothing about a "patent", right?

Comment: @leemes Copyright and patent (as noun) are synonyms. A patent delivers rights on the product. If you prefer, "brevet, marque et modèles déposés" is like "All rights reserved". "brevet, marque et modèles déposés" has no equivalent in english. I only saw "All rights reserved" or "Copyrights"

Comment: Okay thank you very much for this clarification!

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Une traduction simpliste plus qu'inadéquate. Je n'ai jamais vu en bas d'une revue (ou tout autre élément possédant des droits) écrit en anglais quelque chose du genre "registered patent, trademark and model". Le problème de la traduction ici, c'est qu'elle est à faire dans le sens français -> anglais donc je n'ai gardé que l'idée principale (que des droits ont été déposés) Si vous avez la traduction anglaise avec les termes juridiques adéquats, allez-y ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is about patents ([*brevets*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/brevet) d'invention), a trademark ([*marque*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/marque)) as well as models ([*modèles*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/mod%C3%A8le)) for the product, which are *registered* ([*déposés*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/d%C3%A9pos%C3%A9) ; there is plural agreement and all three components are registered). The past participle refers to a technical meaning of [*dépôt*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9p%C3%B4t):

> *Dépôt d'une marque, d'un modèle, etc.* Formalité administrative par laquelle un commerçant acquiert la propriété de sa création et la
>   protection de sa marque, de son modèle, etc. [*TLFi*]

In so many words that is an administrative formality, the filing of some document to some registrar to protect one's work etc. An [overview](http://www.inpi.fr/fr/l-inpi/la-propriete-industrielle/qu-est-ce-que-la-propriete-industrielle.html) of some concepts of intellectual property/copyright in France may be useful; the patent, trademark and [model](http://www.inpi.fr/fr/dessins-et-modeles/qu-est-ce-qu-un-dessin-ou-un-modele/ce-qui-peut-etre-protege.html) can be registered individually, [depending](http://www.inpi.fr/fr/l-inpi/la-propriete-industrielle/comment-proteger-vos-creations.html). For instance registering a drawing/model can grant product sale [exclusivity](http://www.inpi.fr/fr/dessins-et-modeles/qu-est-ce-qu-un-dessin-ou-un-modele/pourquoi-deposer-un-dessin-et-modele.html) in France for a term.

---

A flyer is usually localized and geared at a specific market, most likely France in this case. The content of a legal notice should not be tampered with to make it look casual, and one should ask the client for guidance here and seek professional advice and indeed not guess. On the other hand, the language is clear and there is no reference whatsoever to a patent pending nor to copyrights in what you presented.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how (or even if) the referenced item (the official name of the product, for example) and the footnote itself  are marked (with asterisks, numbers, “MD”s [or even with nothing at all]) in the original French flyer, I would mark them in the translated flyer with asterisks and include the following footnote text after the asterisk at the bottom:

> - The [insert official name of product] is a protected trademark and
>     is protected [internationally (if true)] by both design and utility
>     patents.  All rights reserved.

Personally, I would follow **each** instance of the product’s official name in the body of the flyer with an asterisk, but you’d probably be ok just using one/(or two) asterisk(s) in the body following either/(both) the product name’s **first appearance** or/(and) its **most prominent appearance** in the flyer.

You will note the use of “**design** [and utility] **patents**,” which is intended to capture the French notion of “modèles déposés,” and “… **utility patents**,” which is meant to cover “brevets [d'invention] déposés.”
  (cf: Regarding a comment made elsewhere, while there is some similarity between and overlap of the protection afforded by “copyrights” and “**design** patents,” personally, I would not say that ‘copyright’ and ‘patent’ are synonyms in this or any other case.)

You will perhaps also note that “**protected** trademark,” instead of “**registered** trademark,” is used to attempt to capture “marque déposée.”  I would avoid using “**registered** trademark” (and especially its abbreviated form/symbol “®”) anywhere on the flyer because of the [perhaps false] impression that its use could give concerning the product name’s official registration status with the US Patent and Trademark Office.

Notwithstanding **any** of the foregoing suggestions, I **urge** you to please heed the [astute advice given elsewhere](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17437/flyer-footnote-about-patent-trade-mark/17489#17489), which bears repeating here (with some emphasis and a parenthetical thought added):

> A flyer is usually localized and geared at a specific market, most
>   likely France in this case. The content of a legal notice **should not
>   be tampered with to make it look casual**, and one should **ask the client
>   for guidance** here and **seek professional advice** and indeed **[neither] guess** (nor follow anonymous advice found on the Internet).

(+1, by the way, for having the admirable chutzpah to argue (successfully so far, and I hope it so remains) that your thought-provoking question  involves “understanding French” and that it’s not purely a request for a translation!)